# WKScriptMessageHandler does not work ios swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please tell me, is there such a code.
When the webview loads, the page sends postMessage.
For some reason, print does not work.

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://web.site/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        config.userContentController = userContentController
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    function printHelloWorld() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("Hello, world!");
    }
    window.onload = printHelloWorld;
</script>
```

Please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: You never tell your webView about your config

Comment: @Gereon Please tell me how to do it right?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Two things you need to take care of is message handler name and configuration should be set before URL gets loaded into `WKWebView`. I have added my answer, Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
    func setupWebView() {
        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self

        self.webView?.load(URLRequest(url:url))
    }
```

Also check if Webkit is sending message correctly and using same message handler name as iOS.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин  Add configuration before loading url into the wkwebview